# Returning collection from pivot attributes query

Tags: laravel

I have two models `Service` and `Environment` and a pivot table `environment_service`.

The pivot table has four columns: `service_id`, `environment_id`, `rfs_id` (an id from the Service table) and `rfs_env_id` (an id from the Environment table).

A service (say finance system) has multiple rows in the pivot table to represent the environments (prod, dev, qa) and the supporting services (say DNS, Database, Identity service, etc) and the relevant environment id of that supporting service.

```
|---------------------------------------------------|
| service_id | environment_id | rfs_id | rfs_env_id |
|---------------------------------------------------|
| 1          | 1              | 34     | 1          |
| 1          | 1              | 13     | 1          |
| 1          | 1              | 26     | 2          |
| 1          | 1              | 112    | 3          |
| 1          | 1              | 43     | 1          |
| 1          | 1              | 7      | 1          |
|---------------------------------------------------|
```

Currently, I have some gnarly code in the view to loop through all rows and check for match on `service_id` and `environment_id` and list all the supporting services (from the rfs_id column).  I'd really like to clean this up but can't  work out the way to get a collection of service objects that are the from the `rfs_id` column for rows that match the first two columns.

The relationships between services and environments, and between services and self-referencing dependencies, are all working fine.  It's when trying to return the pivot attribute column as a collection that I'm struggling.

### Update:

This is the code that I am currently using in the view.

```
@foreach($environment->services as $rfs)
    @php($s = \App\Service::find($rfs->pivot->rfs_id))
    @if ($rfs->pivot->service_id === $service->id)
        <strong>{{ Html::link(url('/services/'.$s->id.'/'.$rfs->pivot->rfs_env_id),$s->service_short_name.'-'.get_env_name($rfs->pivot->rfs_env_id)) }}</strong>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: Can you show the code you have so far?

Comment: I've added the code I've been using in the view

Comment: Is `$s` and `$service` meant to be the same variable? If not, where are you getting `$service` from?